# VBA Macro no longer works when used as a COM Add-In (VB.NET) (Mail Merge function)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, vba

I have the below code. Originally, the code was a VBA macro that I built. It ended up working perfectly (sending word doc as an e-mail to a desired range of recipients, iterating through each row). The function begins at the `Sub SendIt_Click` (very last sub) in the code. The rest is for the add-in. When I click the button in Excel, the MsgBox's work, but the code doesn't send anything. It worked in Excel VBA, but I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working here.

Update: It does open the word doc, just doesn't send e-mail.

```
Imports Extensibility
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core

<GuidAttribute("209AD741-0B95-4931-80CF-4DCE33B761C9"), ProgIdAttribute("MailMerge.Connect")> _
Public Class Connect

    Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2

    Private applicationObject As Object
    Private addInInstance As Object
    Dim WithEvents SendIt As CommandBarButton

    Public Sub OnBeginShutdown(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnBeginShutdown
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Notify the user you are shutting down, and delete the button.
        MsgBox("MailMerge Add-in is unloading.")
        SendIt.Delete()
        SendIt = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnAddInsUpdate(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnAddInsUpdate
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnStartupComplete(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnStartupComplete

        Dim oCommandBars As CommandBars
        Dim oStandardBar As CommandBar

        On Error Resume Next
        ' Set up a custom button on the "Standard" command bar.
        oCommandBars = applicationObject.CommandBars
        If oCommandBars Is Nothing Then
            ' Outlook has the CommandBars collection on the Explorer object.
            oCommandBars = applicationObject.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars
        End If

        oStandardBar = oCommandBars.Item("Standard")
        If oStandardBar Is Nothing Then
            ' Access names its main toolbar Database.

            oStandardBar = oCommandBars.Item("Database")

        End If

        ' In case the button was not deleted, use the exiting one.
        SendIt = oStandardBar.Controls.Item("My Custom Button")
        If SendIt Is Nothing Then

            SendIt = oStandardBar.Controls.Add(1)
            With SendIt
                .Caption = "Send to Mail Group with Outlook"
                .Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption

                ' The following items are optional, but recommended. 
                ' The Tag property lets you quickly find the control 
                ' and helps MSO keep track of it when more than
                ' one application window is visible. The property is required
                ' by some Office applications and should be provided.

                .Tag = "MailMerge"

                ' The OnAction property is optional but recommended. 
                ' It should be set to the ProgID of the add-in, so that if
                ' the add-in is not loaded when a user clicks the button,
                ' MSO loads the add-in automatically and then raises
                ' the Click event for the add-in to handle. 

                .OnAction = "!<MyCOMAddin.Connect>"

                .Visible = True
            End With
        End If

        ' Display a simple message to show which application you started in.
        MsgBox("Started in " & applicationObject.Name & ".")

        oStandardBar = Nothing
        oCommandBars = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection

        On Error Resume Next
        If RemoveMode <> Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode.ext_dm_HostShutdown Then _
           Call OnBeginShutdown(custom)

        applicationObject = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection

        MsgBox("On Connection In MailMerge")
        applicationObject = application
        addInInstance = addInInst

        ' If you aren't in startup, manually call OnStartupComplete.
        If (connectMode <> Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup) Then _
           Call OnStartupComplete(custom)

    End Sub

    Private Sub SendIt_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton, ByRef CancelDefault As Boolean) Handles SendIt.Click
        MsgBox("SendIt button was pressed!")

        'Dimension variables.
        Dim OL As Object, MailSendItem As Object
        Dim myxl As Excel.Application
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim wd As Word.Application
        Dim toRange = InputBox("Input cell range in R1:C1 format.", "Input range", "B3:B4")
        Dim subj = InputBox("Input subject.", "Input subject", "TESTING")

        wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        Dim doc As Word.Document
        'On Error Resume Next

        'Assigns Word file to send
        wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

        If wd Is Nothing Then
            wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            'blnWeOpenedWord = True (MAY NOT NEED THIS)
        End If

        doc = wd.Documents.Open _
        (FileName:="H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
        'Set itm = doc.MailEnvelope.Item

        'Starts Outlook session
        OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item

        myxl = GetObject(, "Excel.application")
        ws = myxl.ActiveSheet

        'Creates message
        For Each xRecipient In ws.Range(toRange)
            With MailSendItem
                .Subject = subj
                .To = xRecipient
                .Cc = xRecipient.Offset(0, 5)
                .Attachments.Add("H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.pdf")
                .Send()
            End With
            doc.Close(SaveChanges:=0)

            wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

            doc = wd.Documents.Open _
         (FileName:="H:\Thought Pieces\Small Cap Liquidity\A Closer Look at Small Cap Liquidity.doc", ReadOnly:=False)
            MailSendItem = doc.MailEnvelope.Item
            myxl.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
        Next xRecipient

        'Ends Outlook session
        OL = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you getting the `toRange` and `subj` prompts as well? Are you getting any errors? also change `.Send()` to `Display` and see if an email is created?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am getting those prompts, but no errors. I just tried it with .Display() and got no e-mail as well. Tricky...the VBA code worked and has been working for quite some time now.

Comment: I am off to the gym. will be back in 1.5 hours. will check it then :)

Comment: Good luck, lift hard! :)

Comment: Update: It does open the word doc, just no sending...

Comment: Put a message box after `For Each xRecipient In ws.Range(toRange)` and see if it is entering the loop?

Comment: Great idea, it enters the loop, but does not iterate through the loop. So I only get one message box when I should have two given the two rows in the array B3:B4.

Comment: Put couple more message boxes inside that for loop and see at which line the code fails...

Comment: Ah, the code stops at .To = xRecipient and the code would work if I substituted xRecipient for a string input...so that means there must be something wrong with either xRecipient or ws.Range...will test those now.

Comment: Use this. `xRecipient.Value.ToString()`

Comment: Beautiful, much progress. So I changed xRecipient in the loop to xRecipient.Value.ToString(). I also changed .Cc = xReciipient.Offset(0, 5) to xReciipient.Offset(0, 5).Value.ToString(). The first e-mail sent perfectly. It did not iterate through and begin the second loop. The current range is input as B3:B4.

Comment: Sorry, chat is firewalled at work. I did figure out the problem though. The Application.Wait wasn't working. I tried System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000) and it also didn't work. I ran it without any waits and the e-mails sent. I'll keep trying new forms of "waiting" because I want to ensure that a huge list doesn't clock the mail servers.

Comment: Try this `myxl.Application.Wait(Now.AddSeconds(20))`

Comment: Wow, please leave an answer in the Answer section so I can mark you as answering this. Thank you for all of your help. It was extremely informational and I appreciate you making me do some of the troubleshooting on my own so that I can learn.

Comment: I added an answer with the explanations and suggesitons as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OP's request, what I am doing is just a postmortem summation :)

Whenever in doubt, debug the code yourself. Step through the code but in situations like this when you are testing your code for a VSTO Add-In, I generally put few message boxes in my code so that I know which line is executing and which is not.

Op followed this approach and found two lines which were the culprit.

```
.To = xRecipient
```

and

```
myxl.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
```

The first one failed because that field expects a string value. It was sorted using

```
.To = xRecipient.Value.ToString()
```

I would **recommend** doing the same for `.CC` field as well.

Regarding the other `Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")` was not being calculated correctly. That is because you have "+" sign. Try doing this in VB.Net

```
MessageBox.Show(Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))
```

[image]

The alternative was to use

```
myxl.Application.Wait(Now.AddSeconds(20))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you for being generous with your time Siddharth.